# How do I calculate value of integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

How do I calculate value of integral?

It's given interval $I=[0,5] \times [0,6]$ how do I calculate $\int_{I} −5xy^3     \; d(x,y)$ ?

What is confusing me is that I don't know should I calculate $\int_{0}^{5}\int_{0}^{6} −5xy^3 \; dx \; dy$? or ?

Comment: Since it is rectangular, the order in which you integrate doesn't matter.

Comment: I get different solutions @Kaynex

Comment: Your bounds have to match your variable. When you integrate y, it should be from 0 to 6. So if you switch the order, you should switch the bounds.

Comment: If switching the order gives you a different result, you've done at least one of the computations wrong. You haven't included this work in your question; if you edit it to include such, you're more likely to get a helpful response.

Comment: Your example above has the wrong bounds.

Comment: Oh so I should but dydx? @Kaynex

Comment: dydx if you want to keep your bounds as above. dxdy if you switch the bounds. Both should work.

Comment: $\int_{[0,5]\times [0,6]} (−5xy^3) d(x,y)= \int_{0}^{5}\int_{0}^{6}( −5xy^3)dxdy$ which is the same as $\int_{0}^{6}\int_{0}^{5}( −5xy^3)dydx$